# Is there more to the Loom universe than just the game?

Tags: video-games, loom

In the post [How does the distaff, in Loom, create music?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16286/how-does-the-distaff-in-loom-create-music), I learned that there is an audio play for the game. Are there any other materials which are part of the Loom universe, such as other games, novels, or comics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, *Loom* stands alone. The audio play was distributed only with the game, on a cassette tape or standard Red Book CD. All physical versions of the game I'm aware of came with a copy of [*The Book of Patterns*](http://www.abandonia.com/files/extras/Book%20Of%20Patterns.zip) in which you noted new drafts as you discovered them. Each draft has a comments about its history, and not all the drafts in the notebook are used in the game.

[There's been some discussion of sequels from the original creators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loom_%28video_game%29#Sequels), but Brian Moriarty has been a little inconsistent on whether or not they were intended to be made from the start, or merely sketched out after *Loom*'s success but never planned.